# Log analytics using Elasticsearch & Kibana - Few queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have just started playing around with ELK to develop our log analytics solution.
I had a few questions regarding the best practices so that I don't make any bad choice to begin with.

This tool will analyze various types of logs to find out and correlate any issue. It will run on multiple 'devices' and each device will be uniquely identifiable with a serial number.

**Question 1)** Is it possible to create a dashboard where the serial number is taken as an user input?
Details: I would like to have 1 dashboard created to analyze various fields and I should be able to specify the serial number of the device as an input. From what I see, I could use filter but then this would need the visualization to be 'edited'. So it appears to be me that right now, if I need to analyze multiple devices then I need to create a dashboard for each of the device. This will be a problem that if I need to modify the dashboard then I will have to make changes to all. The problem can be minimized by importing additional dashboards as a JSON file, still it is inconvenient.
Is there a better way that I am not aware of?

**Question 2)** On the main dashboard, I want to show a heatmap of various 'services' and their status as a time series. For e.g. say I am monitoring, CPU, memory, network and our service then I want to see something like below:

[image: Heatmap example]

Now the heatmap visualization doesn't provide a way to uniquely specify the condition. I generated above image by populating dummy data where values were one of 0,1,2,3. Which means that I need to create such data periodically which the visualization can then use. Is there any built-in mechanism (scheduled jobs for e.g.) provided by ELK to do such processing. One option could be to run an external problem which queries Elasticsearch, fetches all the relevant information, analyzes it and puts it back into Elasticssearch. Is that the only way?

If there are any other suggestions, please feel free to share. Thanks.

Comment: For the 2nd question, I am considering doing all the heavy lifting before sending the data to Elasticsearch. I will implement a custom Beats plugin to send all the relevant data to Elasticsearch.